# Only display dropdown menu contents if selected In A PHP Mail

Tags: php, html, email, drop-down-menu, ternary-operator

I created an HTML form that is being sent via PHP Mail. Everything works great, but I want to simplify it so that in the email that gets sent, only the dropdown menus that have actual selections show up. Right now it's set up so that every single dropdown menu shows up in the email, even if the user selected 0. I have quite a few dropdowns already, and a bunch more to add so the email is going to get really messy quick.

Logically, a simple if statement should do the job, but I'm unsure how to do that since I only have one line `$email_body=""` to send content to the email, and I can't insert an if/else statement in there. I looked into ternary operators, but my PHP knowledge is limited and I couldn't get it to work. Thanks!

HTML (simplified just to get an idea)

```
<form>    
  <div class="tab-content clearfix">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="carpet-cleaning">
            <h3 class="options-text">Carpet Cleaning Options</h3>
                <!--how many bedrooms-->
                <label class="control-label" for="carpet_cleaning">Bedrooms</label><br>
                <select class="form-control-1" id="carpet_cleaning" name ="bedrooms_selection">
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                </select>
                <!--how many dining rooms-->
                <br><label class="control-label" for="dining_rooms">Dining Rooms</label><br>
                <select class="form-control-1" id="dining_rooms" name="dining_selection">
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <!--how many family rooms-->
                    <br><label class="control-label" for="family_rooms">Family Rooms</label><br>
                <select class="form-control-1" id="family_rooms" name="family_room_selection">
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                </select>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
$bedrooms = $_POST['bedrooms_selection'];
$diningRooms = $_POST['dining_selection'];
$familyRooms = $_POST['family_room_selection'];
$email_subject = "Price Quote";
$email_body="Carpet Services Needed: \n Bedrooms: $bedrooms \n Dining Rooms: $diningRooms \n Family Rooms: $familyRooms";
$to = "jon@example.com";
$headers = "From: $email";
mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers);
header("Location: http://example.com");
?>
```

So to simplify, if a user chooses 0 in a dropdown menu, I don't want it to show up in the email being sent. Can't figure this out with just the one string that won't allow for an if/else statement.

Comment: Sidenote: Technically; your POST arrays will fail.

Comment: Can you elaborate? It's working as of now, but I would like to know what you mean. I'm pretty new to PHP so an explanation would be really helpful.

Comment: It's ok, never mind. Your *"(simplified just to get an idea)"* seems to mean that the method was left out.

Comment: Oh yep, exactly. Thanks for looking out for that though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare with if and then build the email_body string

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['bedrooms_selection'])){
$services[]='Bedrooms: '.$_POST['bedrooms_selection'];
}
if(!empty($_POST['dining_selection'])){
$services[]='Dining Rooms: '.$_POST['dining_selection'];
}
if(!empty($_POST['family_room_selection'])){
$services[]='Family Rooms: '.$_POST['family_room_selection'];
}
if($services){
$email_subject = "Price Quote";
$email_body='Carpet Services Needed: \n'.implode("\n",$services);
$to = "jon@example.com";
$headers = "From: $email";
mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers);
header("Location: http://example.com");
}
else{
echo 'You have to select at least one service';
}
?>
```

Comment: Ok, this is more what I was looking for. So each service will get declared and put into an array if it's not empty, is that correct? And then you just display the array with `$services`?

Comment: Yes. Zero is empty. And unless declared a variable is false. The array just holds the displayable info.